# Declare an OleVariant and IEnumVariant in Inno Setup

Tags: com, inno-setup, ole, pascalscript

I have a function for getting BIOS serial numbers in the code section that works in Delphi but it doesn't recognize the variable declarations. How do I get around this.

```pascal
var
  FSWbemLocator : OleVariant;
  FWMIService   : OleVariant;  

function GetWMIstring(const WMIClass, WMIProperty:string): string;
var
  FWbemObjectSet: OleVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OleVariant;
  oEnum         : lEnumVariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  Result:='';
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('Select %s from %s',[WMIProperty, WMIClass]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
    if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value) then
      Result:=FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value;

  FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: Use `Variant` instead of `OleVariant`. And `SWbemObjectSet` you can enumerate in a loop like `for I := 0 to FWbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do FWbemObject := FWbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);` since Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks I think I have changed the code as surgested. //  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as olEnumVariant;
  for I := 0 to FWbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do 
    FWbemObject := FWbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
//  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
//    if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value) then
      Result:=FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value; But I know get an error "FWbemObjectSet Unspecified error". I have also changed all variables to varients.