# Inno Setup: Iterate/Enumerate through Firewall Rules / IEnumVariant

Tags: com, inno-setup, firewall, enumeration, ole

I have a similar question like Daniel Rogers about how to declare an `IEnumVariant` in Inno Setup.
[Declare an OleVariant and IEnumVariant in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005354/declare-an-olevariant-and-ienumvariant-in-inno-setup)

I'm writing some extra functionality for our setup, in this case I want to add and remove firewall rules during install/uninstall. There are plenty good pointers with examples on the internet to do that. So that's not the problem, it's already done.

But now I want to iterate/enumerate the existing firewall rules but that's the part where I'm struggling with :-( I can't get it to work, unfortunately Inno Setup doesn't recognize the `IEnumVariant` type so the examples who's are
written in Delphi are not going to work.

If I lookup the Microsoft API documentation about the `INetFwRules` interface
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netfw/nn-netfw-inetfwrules then it looks like it that the only
way to enumerate/iterate is to use the `_NewEnum` function. (which is returning an `IEnumVariant`)

So does anybody have some pointers (or mini example) to work around or deal with the above problem?

I also have some issue's when I'm trying to get one single rule through the `FwRules.Item` function, Inno Setup just keeps saying
*"Ongeldig aantal parameters"* (something like *"invalid parameter count"*).

```
var
  lcFwPolicy : Variant;
  lcFwRules  : Variant;
  lcFwRule   : Variant;
  //lcEnum     : IVariantEnum;
begin
  try
    lcFwPolicy  := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
    lcFwRules   := lcFwPolicy.Rules;
 
    lcFwRules.Item('a fwrule name', lcFwRule); <----- this call is causing "invalid parameter count"
  except
    Log(GetExceptionMessage);
    Log('>>> FirewallRuleExists Exception !!!');
  end;
end;
```

But the most important part of my question is about the enumeration of the firewall rules, if that is possible then the other question is less important.

I'll hope there is somebody out there with the golden solution/workaround.

Comment: Well written for first question. +1. You might briefly mention why you need to iterate FW rules? And does it need to happen inside an installer? This may help others find a solution for you. Is your installer allowed to call an outside script or exe? If inno isn't capable this may be the only alternative.

Comment: Do you have to iterate the rules to test if a specific rule exists? Just use `lcFwRule := lcFwPolicy.Rules.Item('rule name')`.

Comment: Hi B.Shea and Martin Prikryl,

First of all thank you for taking the time to read my post and reply'ing it.

Good point B. Shea, i didn't mentioned that points. My goal is (and a direct answer to Martin's first question) 
that i want to:
a.) Check if an FW rule exists, if the rule is allready exists than i don't need to (re)-install the 
FW rule. For the uninstall part this is less important because i can make the call to delete the FW rule, it doesn't
matter if the rule is exists or not. Deleting it will not cause any error. But on the other hand... i want to do it ....

Comment: 'by the book' and take the approach when uninstalling, first check if it exists, if exists then make the delete call.

b.) Itterate through the rules so i can check by (for example) if a rule allready existst for a particular filename, 
or a specific servicename, and maybe checking it on filename, servicename and protocol and/or ports. their are a 
many way's to register a application into the windows firewall. And the "Fwrule name" doesn't make it fail safe to 
guarantee that the rule for an specific file/services exists. Unfortunally rulenames aren't unique they can exists .....

Comment: multiple times with the same name but for other applications.

At the other question about in or outside the installer... it's preferable to do it all inside the inno installer, 
this because three reasons:
1. The Adding and Deleting of FW rules allready exists in my installer.
2. To put it in a DLL is a posibility but i can be a little bit difficult (and harder to debug) to interface with
it via Inno. eg. Passing strings or Structs is sometimes a bit tricky and causes many head brokens before (read: I) 
have found or fixed it. ;-) but... it's an option.  ......

Comment: 3. And maybe the most important reason... if i put it in a DLL or external EXE, then a have big challenge because
i don't want to physically install this DLL or EXE but extract it runtime from the setup into the memory. 
(this is something i allready do for some dll's) but... the UnInstaller needs also this file and during this time
of writing it is not possibile whitin inno to embedded this file so it can be extracted when needed during uninstall.
I know Martin has written a perfect example for doing this, really martin... geniously found! +2 but that involves  .....

Comment: the powershell. and that's one step to far for this issue.

I also tried your suggestion Martin, that was my first thought also but unfortnally it raises an error/exception.
in the example below i've tried three variants, but all three failes. the first one i've tried because of de API 
description of Microsoft. (two parameters for the Item function see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netfw/nf-netfw-inetfwrules-item)
......

Comment: `lcFwPolicy  := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
    lcFwRules   := lcFwPolicy.Rules;
    
    lcFwRules.Item('TestFwRule', lcFwRule);          //causes the error msg: Exception: Ongeldig aantal parameters. (Invalid parameter count)
    lcFwRule := lcFwRules.Item('TestFwRule');        //causes the error msg: Exception: : .
    lcFwRule := lcFwPolicy.Rules.Item('TestFwRule'); //causes the error msg: Exception: : .`

Looking forward to your reactions/suggestions.

With regards,

Richard Lichtendahl
The Netherlands - Europe (+1 GMT)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, and yes your also right with your code example because it's declared in the 'DispIntf:  INetFwRulesDisp' of Jedi also like 'function Item(const Name: WideString): INetFwRule; dispid 4;'